# Plastic deformation in steel cable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, stress-strain

Assume we have a steel cable with length 1m and it's diameter is 15mm. The cable has a youngs modulus = 200GPa, yield strength = 500MPa and tensile strength = 580 MPa. We attach a brick that weighs 10 tons at the end of the cable (pure strain). Will we see plastic deformation?

I know that the stress = $\frac{F}{A_0}$. Now if the brick is hanging from the cable, I assume $F = 10 000 * 9.81 = 98 100 N $.

So we get stress = $\frac{98100N}{176.715mm^2}$ = 555.13$\frac{N}{mm^2}$
where I used A = area of crossection = $\pi*7.5^2$

Not sure where to go from here tho...